# Arrows in C. Inserting a new element in the middle

Tags: c, list, structure

```
void New_list ( struct el * *start, struct el * *end )
{

    struct el *g;
    int x;
    puts (Insert elements, to finish insert 0:" );

    *start = NULL;
    *end = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    while( x != 0 )
    {
        if ( *start == NULL)
        {
            g = (struct el *) malloc(sizeof(struct el));
            g->elem = x;
            g->next = NULL;
            *end = g;
            *start = g;
        }
        else
        {
            g = (struct el *) malloc(sizeof(struct el));
            g ->elem = x;
            g ->next = NULL;
            (*end)->next = g;
            *end = g;
        }
        scanf( "%d", &x );
    }
}
```

I have this list and i need to insert a new element after a k element (k is from keyboard). I'm new to the arrows so i can't figure it how to do it.

Comment: I suggest to study some basics. http://www.amazon.com/dp/0131103628/?tag=stackoverfl08-20

Comment: When pasting code, please make sure you paste actual (and compilable) code. Oh, and [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: It would also be helpful to show the code you *tried* to make work, not some unrelated function. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: If you are "new to arrows", you should make sure you understand "arrows" (i.e., pointers), before asking for "how to make my list handling work"...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your structure has `elem` and `next`

When you insert a new element in the middle what you need to do is

```
  +------+-------+         +-------+-------+
  |      |       |         |       |       |
  |      |       |         |       |       |
  |   1  |   +------------>|   2   |   +------------>
  |      |       |         |       |       |
  +------ -------+         +------- -------+
   elem    next              elem    next


  +------+-------+                                  +-------+-------+
  |      |       |                                  |       |       |
  |      |       |                                  |       |       |
  |   1  |   +-------+                +------------>|   2   |   +------------>
  |      |       |   |                |             |       |       |
  +------ -------+   |                |             +------- -------+
   elem    next      |                |               elem    next
                     |   +-------+----|---+
                     |   |       |    |   |
                     |   |       |    |   |
                     |   |   3   |    |   |
                     +-->|       |    +   |
                         |       |        |
                         +------- --------+
```

First you need to traverse  to the block where you want to insert the new block. say `k` is 1

You need to save the value of the `next` of this block.

You create a new block and assign this `next` to the `next` of the new block.

The `next` of the block preceeding the new block will have the address of the new block